# Getting the content of filebrowse

Tags: php, html

is it possible to get the content of file browse upload (e.g. image/doc) from one page and display it to another page, in PHP?

```
Filebrowse <input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

Comment: Please just read documentation on File Uploads. Keyword is $_FILES

Comment: Not sure whether you are asking about the actual upload procedure here, or just about reading the contents of a folder with PHP …? Either way, you should be able to get clarafication on both, by doing a bit of research. Please avoid asking “is it possible” questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,by using `file_get_contents()` you can get the whole contents of the file and to pass it onto another page you can post it directly